# CSS: floating over text

Tags: css

I want to make a delete icon appear when you mark over the content(text). Now I have done this, but when it appears it moves the text in a ugly way.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/AB4Ls/10/

How can I make it "float over" it, so it dont affect the text but still appears

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of javascript at all, if you use `.aL_Content:hover .delButton` css selector to display button.

Comment: Using the CSS pseudo hover depends on which browsers you need to support of course - it won't work in IE6. http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t16

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to "absolutely" position the close button, rather than float it in the content.

Simple add this to your CSS:

```
.aL_Content{
    position: relative
}

.delButton{
position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

And delete the `float:right` from `.delButton`.

Comment: And if you don't want the image to appear over the text you can simply add some right padding to the .aL_Content div.

Answer (score 1):

I changed your markup in your example on the lowest block.

I changed the input to a div and had it separate from your original div, then `position: relative;` to `.aL_Content` and `position: absolute;` to `.delbutton`.

It's important to take away the float attribute, as this is what was causing your text to wrap around the new element.

You can see my changes [here at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/fNbZ6/1/).

Answer (score 1):

When using Bootstrap 4, according to [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/)
your could implement @ajcw's answer using these classes.

```
<div class="position-relative">
    <div class="position-absolute">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

Then you should supply the `right:0;` or your styling by your preference. Either by class or `style` attribute.